# Where can I find a NotSerializableException in Websphere 7 EJB 2.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization, ejb, websphere

I know classes of parameters and return values of EJB method calls need to be Serializable. Unfortunately I forgot to set this on a parameter or a return value, and do not know which one. My application has a lot of methods and a lot of parameters and a lot were added since the last operational test. Unfortunately the error from Websphere is not telling me which class is not Serializable. The error below is what Websphere is telling me on the EJB client side.

```
CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f896 No; nested exception is: 
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : purge_calls:1927 Reason: CONN_ABORT (1), State: ABORT (5)  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 896  completed: No
```

On the server side I cannot find anything about this. Is there any easy way to find out which class is not serializable?

Comment: Adding a comment because I'm not certain, but I would try enabling `ORBRas=all` trace and setting the `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` JVM system property, and then hope that the ORB trace includes the exception stack trace with the extended serialization debug info.

Comment: @bkail: enabling the ORBRas=all was enough to find the SerializableException. I followed the instructions [How do I set up Object Request Broker trace in Websphere Application Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmFYWxheGB8&cm_mc_uid=95199957401813974772050&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1448266450) and found the class which was not Serializable. Thanks.